# How to get attributes value of html inputs in django views

Tags: jquery, django

I have html input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="download_number" class="corecharinputwidget form-control" size="10" maxlength="30" style="font-size: smaller;margin-top: 30px;" placeholder="Enter Document Number" id="id_download_number" pk="1">
```

and I want to recieve pk attribute value in django view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery Ajax methods like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        method: "get",
        url: "your url",
        data: { 'download_number_pk': $('#id_download_number').prop('pk') }, 
        success: function (data) {
        // handle with your revived data
        }
    });
```

In django views just check the request like this:

```
if request.GET.get('download_number_pk',None):
    pk=request.GET.get('download_number_pk')
    //  You have received html input attribute
```